# Change position of commit message length indicator

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

With the update from PhpStorm 2016.3 to 2017.1 came an improved committing interface, and a handy indicator to show how long the message is. The only issue is that I cannot find a way to change the default position, which is after the 72nd character.

> [image: phpstorm commit message input]

I'd like to know if there's any way to change the indicator's position to accommodate the the more conventional 50 or GitHub's 69 character limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With the update from PhpStorm 2016.3 to 2017.1 came an improved committing interface, and a handy indicator to show how long the message is.

Cannot say anything about interface improvements ... but message length indicator is available for quite some time now (e.g. [this ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151618) was answered over 1 year ago).

---

In any case:

`Settings/Preferences | Version Control --> Commit message right margin (columns)`

Screenshot is from 2016.3.3

[image]

The only difference is that in 2017.1 this option is enabled even though my settings were imported from 2016.3 where it's disabled.

Comment: Huh, guess I only found out about it because of the setting import bug. I've thought up until now that there was no such option. I meant improvements as in the fixed with font and the margin, but evidently that's not new as you mentioned.